# Tkinter- Listbox Select the Inverse of Currently Highlighted Items

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a button that will automatically select the inverse of what is currently selected. I have poorly attempted to try and create this feature in the code below but it does not work. In my code I am trying to highlight everything and then deselect what was originally selected, which would be the equivalent of getting the inverse. Can someone take a look at my code and see what is wrong?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

main = Tk()
main.geometry("+50+150")
frame = ttk.Frame(main, padding=(3, 3, 12, 12))
frame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, S, E, W))

lstbox = Listbox(frame, selectmode=MULTIPLE, width=20, height=10)
lstbox.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=2)

for i in range(10):
    lstbox.insert(0, i)

def select(evt):
    global selected
    global selection
    selection = lstbox.curselection()
    for i in selection:
        selected = lstbox.get(i)
        print(selected)

lstbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', select)

def select_inverse():
    lstbox.selection_set(0, END)
    lstbox.selection_clear(selected, selected)

btn = ttk.Button(frame, text="Inverse", command=select_inverse)
btn.grid(column=1, row=1)

main.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there but you don't need actual values of listbox items. You can do your operation using indexes only.

Also, you don't need (at least not for this particular task), `select` method you are binding to `lstbox`. You can directly work in `select_inverse`.

```
def select_inverse():
    selection = lstbox.curselection()
    lstbox.selection_set(0, END) 
    for item in selection:
        lstbox.selection_clear(item)
```